# WhatsApp Backup from low storage iPhone: How can I keep my old media and back up new chats at the same time?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore, whatsapp.app

I lost my iPhone 13 Pro Max **(512GB)** and I had **everything backed up on iCloud** including WhatsApp chats.

I got a new iPhone 14 Pro Max **(256GB)** and all of my WhatsApp chats recovered, but **not the media**, because I didn’t have the storage for it. (See screenshot)

[image]

So, I deleted stuff and had more than enough space to recover the media.

[image]

Started downloading, I kept the screen on just to make sure that it downloaded without interruption, got up to 48%, and the app crashed

[image]

Once it crashed, I opened the app back in, and it went from 48% to 14%

All of that “Media Data” that downloaded and it’s not showing up on the progress bar, turned into “System Data” storage on my iPhone

[image]

And suddenly I didn’t have storage space to recover the media, just because Whatsapp media failure took up a lot of “System Data” on my iPhone storage.

Then I deleted more stuff on my iPhone (15GB more) to have storage for the recovery and proceeded to download once again.

[image]

It got into the “Finishing up” phase and then WhatsApp crashed again.

[image]

And now all of that downloaded media, turned into “System Data” storage, and once again left me with no space available for media recovery, I am unable to delete any more things on my iPhone.

My storage went from:

90 GB out of 256 GB (First try recovering media)

134 GB out of 256 GB (After the app crashed mid-recovery and turned the data into system data)

154 GB out of 256 GB (After the second WhatsApp failure on recovering media)

[image]

[image]

Over 70 GB of “System Data” under the iPhone storage options
I’m running iOS 17.0.3, iPhone 14 Pro Max, 256 GB, Running the Latest version of WhatsApp

Whatsapp support told me to delete and reinstall the app because my restore media backup is corrupted, the backup is from May 22, and I have recent messages and media **after that date**.

Should I click on **Skip media restore** and back up again? Will that delete my previous data (media) from the servers?

Should I Uninstall and install it again? Will that delete my chats and media created after my backup?

What should I do if I want to keep my old media and new chats and media created after the backup?